# VBA - Error on Table creation

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Sub CreateTable()
MsgBox "Like this?"
    'Add Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library
    Dim strConnectString        As String
    Dim objConnection           As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strDbPath               As String
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    'Set database name and DB connection string--------
    strDbPath = "E:\Books\Works\Newdb.mdb"
    '==================================================
    MsgBox "created"
    strConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strDbPath & ";"
    MsgBox "created2"
    'Connect Database; insert a new table
    'Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    With objConnection
        .Open strConnectString
        .Execute "CREATE TABLE MyTable ([EmpName] text(50) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[Address1] text(150) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[Address2] text(150) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[City] text(50) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[State] text(2) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[PIN] text(6) WITH Compression, " & _
                 "[SIN] decimal(6))"
    End With

End Sub
```

I am getting an error as below

```
****Run-Time Error  '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Automation error
Unspecified error****
```

Comment: have you tested your sql statement directly in access?

Comment: The code works for ms access 2010 using ACE provider.

Comment: @santosh: i am using 2007

Comment: @user2930371 Database is mdb or accdb ?

Comment: @Santosh: I am using MDB

Comment: but i am creating a new table in access DB that is already created.

Comment: so you should be altering the table instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @user2930371 Apologies for misleading link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried & Tested code (for mdb)

```
Sub CreateTable()
'Add Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library
    Dim strConnectString As String
    Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strDbPath As String

    'Set database name and DB connection string--------
    strDbPath = "E:\Books\Works\Newdb.mdb"
    '==================================================

    strConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strDbPath & ";"

    'Connect Database; insert a new table
    Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    With objConnection
        .Open strConnectString

        strSQL = "CREATE TABLE MyTable " & _
                 "(EmpName TEXT(150)," & _
                 "Address1 TEXT(150)," & _
                 "Address2 TEXT(150)," & _
                 "City TEXT(50)," & _
                 "State TEXT(2)," & _
                 "PIN TEXT(6)," & _
                 "SIN number)"

        .Execute strSQL
    End With

    Set objConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So was it the `WITH Compression` that was causing the problem with the original code in the question? In other words, is `WITH Compression` supported under ACE.OLEDB but not under Jet.OLEDB?

Comment: @GordThompson Honestly I am not aware of this. I just goggled for code and with few tweaks this code worked.

Comment: No, that wasn't the issue. In fact, I cannot reproduce the error at all.

Comment: @GordThompson For me it worked when access dB was in 2010 (accdb) using ACE provider but when I downloaded a sample mdb from rogers access library and try to run the OP code I did get the same run time error as mentioned in Q.

Comment: @user2930371 Glad it worked. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. 
Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/about)